# Can't assign cell entries

Tags: matlab, neural-network, cell-array

I am using a neural network which has 2 nodes in the output layer, hence I get a cell `v_cell{1,number_of_layers} =[7 ; 8]`for eg. as output which i want to assign to to quantities v_x and v_y through

```
v_x = cell(1,4999);v_y = cell(1,4999);

[v_x{1,epochs} v_y{1,epochs}] = deal(v_cell{1,number_of_layers})';,
```

but I get the following error :

```
Error using  '  Too many output arguments.
```

Comment: Why do you have `'` at the end?

Comment: @Argyll it means error using transpose

Comment: I am asking why do *you* put `'` after `deal()`? What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want the 1st and 2nd elements of your output redistributed or do you want to duplicate your output vector? (Please edit into question directly.) The other thing is please ask questions using [minimally self-contained examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People can infer the syntax of your *custom* function `v_cell`, yes. Still, there is no real necessity of blending in your neutral network scenario.

Answer (score 1):

First : `deal` doesn't return one array, so transpose it makes no sense.

Then `v_cell{1,number_of_layers}` is an array so `[v_x{1,epochs},v_y{1,epochs}] = deal(v_cell{1,number_of_layers});` distributes it in `v_x{1,epochs}` and `v_y{1,epochs}` as said in the help:

> [Y1, Y2, Y3, ...] = deal(X) copies the single input to all the
>   requested outputs. It is the same as Y1 = X, Y2 = X, Y3 = X, ...

What you want is Y1=X(1), Y2=X(2),...

You could try with a custom function `extract` with non-restricted number of output argument:

```
[v_x{1,epochs},v_y{1,epochs}] = extract(v_cell{1,number_of_layers});
```

where `extract` may be defined in `extract.m`:

```
function varargout=extract(vect)
if ~strcmp(class(vect),class([0,0]))
    error('Input argument is not a constant');
end
if numel(vect)~=nargout
    error('Number of element in vect and number of output args are different');
end
varargout=num2cell(vect);
end
```

Would be nice if there were a builtin function to do that but I don't know if it exists. I've tried with an anonymous function but not managed to make it work.